# how to inject object into a jersey resource that is created programatically

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Hello everyone i just want to know is there a way to inject an object into a jersey resource that is created via the programmatic api for resource creation for example in a normal jersey resource we can do this

```
@Path("/Product")
public class ProductService {
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  // injection via factory
  public Product getProduct(@Context ContextHelper ctx) {
    // custom logic
  }
}
```

Now how can we achieve the same thing while creating a jersey resource programatically such as

```
Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder("Product");
resourceBuilder.addMethod("GET").handledBy(new MyInflector());
// How to inject ^^ here?
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense where your arrow is pointing. Where exactly do you want it injected? In the Inflector?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha what i meant was that just like i have injected ContextHelper via a custom factory how can i achieve the same thing in the programmatic api version like how can i inject the same ContextHelper object in the resource being created programmatically?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha in the inflector's apply method i guess

Comment: That's impossible. You can't just magically add arguments to a method.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha allright sir thanks for clearing things out. Would appreciate it if you could direct me to some links or documentation describing what you have stated..

Comment: @PaulSamsotha okay but could it also be not injected to some field in inflector class?

Comment: To what? The fact that you can't add arguments to methods after compilation?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha no sir i know about that fact. It's just that you wrote its impossible first so i wrote that comment:-)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but have you tried to use the usual dependency injection?

Comment: yeah i have tried injecting it into a field but got errors that i cant seem to remember now

Comment: Are you sure you did it right? [Here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/faa809da43538ce31076b50f969b4bd64caa5ac9/tests/integration/servlet-3-inflector-1/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/tests/integration/servlet_3_inflector_1/MyInflector.java) is an integration test from the Jersey source code where they are injecting something,